# Replace the first line with spaces

Tags: c, replace, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to replace the first line with spaces, what is it that is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    char text[5][10]={
        {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
        {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
        {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
        {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
        {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
    };


    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        text[i]=' ';
    }

    for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        printf("%s\n",text[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go one further - you're overwriting the null at the end of the first 'line'. Set your loop to iterate over 0..9:

```
for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
        text[0][i]=' ';
}
```

Comment: ah cheers! i was wondering why it just pushed the a's backwards when it was (int i=0;i<10;i++)

Answer (score 3):

You're not indexing "across", you're indexing "down". Try:

```
text[0][i] = ' ';
```

to overwrite the first line's characters.

Also note that you have an [Obi-wan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error); your loop overwrites the terminating character with a space as well.

Comment: Where's the character pointer? It's just a flat array of 50 elements. Should compile without problems.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

1. You are only supplying one dimension in your first loop. It should be:

   ```
   text[0][i]=' ';
   ```
2. You only have 9 'a's, but you are replacing with 10 spaces, so you'll overwrite the null terminator of the first line. so I think you're whole loop should be:

```
for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
    text[0][i]=' ';
}
```

Comment: Using a single dimenstion when working with multi-dimensional arrays is perfectly legal in C.
The problem just lies in the second problem mentioned in the solution, where you try to replace 10 'a' and there are only 9 in each line of the array.

Answer (score 3):

you will have to use

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        text[0][i]=' ';
    }
```

Now `text` will be

```
text[5][10]={
                                  {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
                                  {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  {'a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  };
```

Or

```
for (int i=0;i<5;i++){
        text[i][0]=' ';
    }
```

Now `text` will become

```
text[5][10]={
                                  {' ','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  {' ','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  {' ','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  {' ','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  {' ','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','\0'},
                                  };
```

Pick whichever solution you wanted. :)

Comment: It didn't pushed 'a' backward but it just changed the value in 0th index of all rows to ' '[space] :), So there is 1 space, 9 'a' and 1 '\0' in every row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should adjust to

```
text[i][0] = ' ';
```

Comment: First line... rather text[0][i] instead of text[i][0]

Comment: sorry, cross post - I agree with ammoQ

Answer (score 1):

```
 for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
     text[0][i]=' ';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- make your array length to  11 like:
  char text[5][10] to char text[5][11] and change the initialization accordingly.
- Chanage your for loop, the condition 'i<10' to 'i<9'

The proble is with index counting.

Answer (score -1):

Its double dimension array and not single dimension ans thats why this will not work.

Comment: It's perfectly legal in C. char[5][10] is the same as char[50] and you're allowed to access the array in both ways.